# cant get two object to the same height

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I cant get the two object to the same height.
The table should be on the left side and the button at center but now the button stays under the table but I dont know why.

Here is [a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Sirzento/0m78z2ta/) for it.

Code:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="text-center">
    <div>
        <table class="table col-sm-3">
            <thead></thead>
            <tbody id="ranking"><tr id="xOJzQ-ik9pNq3OKbAAAA"><td>1.</td><td style="width:10px" class="align-middle"><div style="background-color:green;width: 10px; height: 10px;"></div></td><td>Name</td><td>0 Pkt.</td></tr><tr id="JaH1T-7XNkBqa2cnAAAB"><td>2.</td><td style="width:10px" class="align-middle"><div style="background-color:RosyBrown;width: 10px; height: 10px;"></div></td><td>dfsdf</td><td>0 Pkt.</td></tr><tr id="jwEfjfA6COOTeG0ZAAAC"><td>3.</td><td style="width:10px" class="align-middle"><div style="background-color:gold;width: 10px; height: 10px;"></div></td><td>ffff</td><td>0 Pkt.</td></tr></tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="button" class="btn" value="" id="buzzer" style="background-color:red; width: 350px; height: 350px; border: solid 50px grey;border-radius: 50px;">
    </div>
</div>
```

Edit: Both sould be at the top, not vertical center.

Comment: Please mention your problem and expected output clearly.

Comment: the problem is that the button is to much down and should be on the same height as the table but somehow the table pushes the button down.

Comment: You are not using the Bootstrap grid system correctly, I encourage you to go though it again.

Comment: you write two div after one another, div is a block element. so, your button will go under table. By the way what is the style property of text-center ?

Comment: There are lots of way positioning html element. You can use css float system or flexbox or css grid as bootstrap. See the documentation for Bootstrap grid system. You are not using in a correct way.

Comment: I tried a few ways but I cant get it to work that the table if left and the button at center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="text-center row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <input type="button" class="btn m-auto" value="" id="buzzer" style="background-color:red; width: 350px; height: 350px; border: solid 50px grey;border-radius: 50px;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Have a look at [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ksiger/haqgb4cu/3/)

Comment: Its the same height yes but I want to let the button stay in the center of the row.

Comment: change second div class to `col-sm-9` and add `margin: auto;` to its content [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ksiger/haqgb4cu/7/) .Bootstrap has `m-auto` class, so you can just add it. [https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/]

Comment: Then the button is at the center of the space left of the table. i want the button at the center of the container/whole row

Comment: @sirzento use `col-sm-6` instead of `col-sm-9`

Comment: @sirzento dont forget to up the answer and check it as right

Comment: Sure, just edit it to the right values of the col classes.